# Functions Giving Performance Issues

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery

My application hangs up on IE and mobile browsers when these functions are fired. Is there anything that stands out as being obviously performance-killing?

```
$this.find('input.bundle-check').live('change', function() {
    var $box = $(this),
    ntn = $box.data().ntn,
    price = $box.data().price,
    savings = $box.data().savings;
    if ($box.is(':checked')) {
        productsBundled[ntn] = {
            "price"     :   price,
            "savings"   :   savings,
            "ntnid"     :   ntn,
            "qty"       :   1
        }; 
        $box.siblings('label').text(' Selected')
        $box.closest('.grid-product').fadeTo(300, 0.5)
    } else {
        $box.siblings('label').text(' Add Item');
        delete productsBundled[ntn];
        $box.closest('.grid-product').fadeTo(300, 1.0)
    }
    refreshSelectedItems(productsBundled);
    $this.find('.itemCount').text(concat('(',objectCount(productsBundled),')'));

})

function refreshSelectedItems(products, remote) {
    var itemntns = [], totalPrice=0.00, totalSavings=0.00;
    products = products || {};
    remote = remote || 2;
    if (objectCount(products) > 0) {
        $.each(products, function(i, item) {
            $qtyBox = $('.selected-item[data-ntn=' + i + '] .cartqty');
            itemntns.push(i);
            totalPrice += (item.price * ($qtyBox.val() || 1));
            totalSavings += (item.savings * ($qtyBox.val() || 1));
                    // console.log('qtyBox', $qtyBox.val())
                }); 

        if(remote > 1) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Includes/pageHelper.cfc',
                type: 'post',
                async: true,
                data: {
                    method: "getBundleSelectedItems",
                    productList: itemntns.join(',')
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var $container = $('.selected-items > span');
                    $container.html(data);
                    $.each($container.find('.selected-item'), function() {
                        var myntn = $(this).data().ntn,
                        $price = $(this).find('.price'),
                        $bunPrice = $('<span />').addClass('bundle-price');

                        $(this).find('.cartqty').val(productsBundled[myntn].qty);

                        if (productsBundled[myntn].savings > 0) {
                            $bunPrice.text(concat(' $', productsBundled[myntn].price.toFixed(2)));
                            $(this).find('em').hide();
                            $price.after($bunPrice.after($('<span />').addClass('sale').text(concat(' You save $', productsBundled[myntn].savings.toFixed(2), '!'))));
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    } else {
        $('.selected-items > span').html('');
    }

    $this.find('.bundle-saving').text(concat("$", totalSavings.toFixed(2)));
    $this.find('.bundle-addons').text(concat("$", totalPrice.toFixed(2)));
    totalPrice = totalPrice + (parseFloat($('.original-products > div:has(:checked)').data().price) * parseInt($('.original-products > div:has(:checked) .cartqty').val()));
    $this.find('.bundle-total').text(concat("$", totalPrice.toFixed(2)));

}
```

Comment: well... live() should no longer be used.. it is deprecated. In newer versions use .on() and in older versions use .delegate() - not sure if this will impact performance ***that*** much, but .live() is known to be slow.

Comment: I typically use `on`, but this content can be loaded with AJAX. maybe this was too much of a shortcut to simply rebinding?

Comment: @KyleMacey If the content can be added after the handler is attached, then bind to a parent element [that is always there] and provide the selector of the children to bind the handler to: `$this.on('click', 'input.bundle-check', handler);` . The API [explains this](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: I always wondered what the advantage was of that syntax... thanks

Comment: it would probably be quicker to use a for() loop instead of $.each(products, function(i, item) {

Comment: This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about [what your code does](//codereview.meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226) and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The current title states your concerns about the code; it needs an [edit] to simply *state the task*; see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things which stand out to me:

```
var $box = $(this),
ntn = $box.data().ntn,
price = $box.data().price,
savings = $box.data().savings;
```

You use `$box.data()` several times; it may be faster to cache the return value of that function.

```
if ($box.is(':checked')) {
```

`:checked` is not a standard CSS selector, so it will be slower than simply:

```
if (this.checked) {
```

Later, you used

```
                $.each($container.find('.selected-item'), function() {
```

I'm not sure if it's faster, but you could just do:

```
                $container.find('.selected-item').each(function() {
```

Finally, this line:

```
totalPrice = totalPrice + (parseFloat($('.original-products > div:has(:checked)').data().price) * parseInt($('.original-products > div:has(:checked) .cartqty').val()));
```

[The `:has` selector is not standard CSS, so it can't use browsers' native functions. instead, consider using the `has()` method instead](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```
totalPrice = totalPrice + (parseFloat($('.original-products').children('div').has(':checked').data().price) * parseInt($('.original-products').children('div').has(':checked').find('.cartqty').val(), 10));
```

Note that I also added the `radix` argument to `parseInt`. A micro-optimization at best, but it does mean the JS engine doesn't need to guess.

Hope that helps.